# Get element width in ELM

Tags: html, elm

i have html like

```
<h1 class = 'block__title' id='title'>Main text</h1>
```

with css:

```
.block__title {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

i can get this element in js with:

```
const title = document.getElementById('title');
```

and doing anything with width `title.offsetWidth+1`

How i can do the same in ELM?
i have:

```
[ h1 [ class "block-title" ]
            [ text (Main text)
            ]
]
```

i need to get width of the element higher for further changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Browser.Dom.getElement` like so:

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Browser.Dom exposing (Element, Error)
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, h1, text)
import Html.Attributes exposing (class, id)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Task


type alias Model =
    { titleWidth : Float }


init : () -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init _ =
    ( { titleWidth = 0 }
    , Browser.Dom.getElement "title" |> Task.attempt GotElement
    )


type Msg
    = GotElement (Result Error Element)


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        GotElement (Err err) ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        GotElement (Ok element) ->
            ( { model | titleWidth = element.element.width }, Cmd.none )


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ h1 [ class "block-title", id "title" ] [ text "Main Title Text" ]
        , div [] [ text <| "Title Width: " ++ String.fromFloat model.titleWidth ]
        ]


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.element
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = \_ -> Sub.none
        }
```

You can find more information in the [getElement docs](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Dom#getElement).

Comment: ty,it's really helpfull
but i can't install browser package,
i got `Your .elm/packages/ directory may be corrupted. I was led to believe that
elm/browser existed, but I could not find anything when I went to look up the
published versions of this package.`
my json is 
` "dependencies": {
  "elm/browser": "1.0.0 <= v < 2.0.0"
}`
maybe do u have any ideas?

Comment: @Слава you should be able to just delete that directory and rebuild - I'd advise to no manually edit the `elm.json` file - use `elm install` instead (this package should already be there - probably as a hidden dependency - so if you could compile your project before you already had it)

Comment: @Carsten i use just `elm install` but browser package no there
i can install http,url-parser etc,but not browser package,looks like this package does not exist

Comment: What version (Elm) are you using?

Comment: @Carsten 0.18.0

Comment: that is the issue right there - this was refactored into different modules with 0.19 - do you need to stick with 0.18?

Comment: I think you should be able to use this: https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/dom/1.1.1/Dom

Comment: @Carsten yes, all project on 0.18

Comment: oops my bad - nope this function is not in DOM - actually not sure if there was anything like this - you probably have to use ports then (I'd really suggest you move at some time - it'll get only worse)

Comment: @Carsten so browser package available only on 0.19?

Comment: yes I think so - things got moved a bit but I could not find something like `getElement` in the 0.18 core libraries

Comment: You can always use a `ports` approach where `getElement` becomes a command port that sends the `id` value to javascript. On javascript side, you get the width and you send it back into Elm using a  subscription port. You might need to track the source of the request and route back the message to its proper origin (page).